# Как обойти “Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1”?

Tags: java, android, admob

Чтобы воспроизвести ошибку нужно несколько раз открыть-закрыть приложение. После 2-5 раз открытия-закрытия, на емуляторе ловлю эту ошибку. По идее это просто загрузка interstitial.

Возможно кто-то выяснил, на каких версиях webview такое происходит? Как вариант, думал просто не показывать рекламу пользователям с такими версиями webview.

Или есть другие идеи, как это можно побороть?

> --------- beginning of crash 09-08 09:08:39.351 9566-9566/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 9566
> (appwebviewcrash) 09-08 09:08:39.454 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: *** *** ***
> *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** 09-08 09:08:39.454 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint:
> 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86_64/generic_x86_64:5.1.1/LMY48X/6695563:userdebug/test-keys' 09-08 09:08:39.454 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: Revision: '0' 09-08
> 09:08:39.454 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86_64' 09-08 09:08:39.454
> 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: pid: 9566, tid: 9566, name: appwebviewcrash >>>
> info.just3soft.appwebviewcrash <<< 09-08 09:08:39.454 1173-1173/?
> I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
> 09-08 09:08:39.459 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: rax 0000000074e84a50 rbx
> 00007fffc8605780 rcx 00007fffc86057d0 rdx 00007f9ffbcc7300 09-08
> 09:08:39.459 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: rsi 0000000000000000 rdi
> 00007fffc8605780 09-08 09:08:39.459 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: r8
> 0000000000000055 r9 0000000012f5d000 r10 00007fffc8605740 r11
> 0000000000000000 09-08 09:08:39.459 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: r12
> 00007f9ffbcc7300 r13 0000000000000001 r14 0000000012c6a580 r15
> 0000000012c6a580 09-08 09:08:39.460 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: cs
> 0000000000000033 ss 000000000000002b 09-08 09:08:39.460 1173-1173/?
> I/DEBUG: rip 00007f9fec3f5230 rbp 0000000013098a40 rsp
> 00007fffc8605740 eflags 0000000000010202 09-08 09:08:39.460
> 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: backtrace: 09-08 09:08:39.460 1173-1173/?
> I/DEBUG: #00 pc 0000000000af7230 /system/lib64/libwebviewchromium.so
> 09-08 09:08:39.460 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: #01 pc 0000000000af775b
> /system/lib64/libwebviewchromium.so
> (Java_com_android_org_chromium_content_browser_webcontents_WebContentsImpl_nativeGetURL+26) 09-08 09:08:39.460 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: #02 pc 000000000000d953
> /data/dalvik-cache/x86_64/system@app@webview@webview.apk@classes.dex
> 09-08 09:08:39.598 1173-1173/? I/DEBUG: Tombstone written to:
> /data/tombstones/tombstone_07

```
device: Android Emulator
system image:
  Release Name: Lollipop
  API Level: 22
  ABI: x86_64
  Target: Android 5.1 (Google APIs)
```

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-***~***" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this);

        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```